# Why not able to add a repository in IBM Installation Manager 1.8.6?

Tags: installation

I have an issue with IBM Installation Manager 1.8.6.  I selected the repository.config file under (IBM/Installation Manager/Eclipse) as the repository. However, when i later on press install, i get the following error message:

```
Repository expected to be an install package for Installation Manager, but repository property RequireContext does not contain expected value: 
RequireContext=InstallKit:im.version=<display version of installable IM>, im.internal.version=<internal version of IM> , 
admin=<admin install command>, user=<user install command>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the repository contains the package that you want to  install.  The repository.config under IBM/Installation Manager/Eclipse does not reference to any packages.  You can find more details from this link.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSDV2W_1.8.5/com.ibm.cic.agent.ui.doc/topics/t_installing_packages.html